# When using an Ag Grid with Angular, is it possible to disable Unbalanced Groups without changing the source data?

Tags: angular6, grouping, ag-grid

When using an Ag Grid with Angular, is it possible to disable Unbalanced Groups without changing the source data?

[This link](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#unbalanced-groups) says that in order to prevent unbalanced groups, you have to change your data to replace nulls or undefineds with blank space characters.  I don't want to change my data.  I tried using a cellRenderer to display nulls and undefineds as blank characters.  This seems like an obvious solution, but my groups were still unbalanced.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is!  You can use the keyCreator property of a column:

```
column.keyCreator = params => {
  return params.value === null || params.value === undefined ? ' ' : params.value;
};
```

Comment: Would you then have to change your grouping to group by keys across the Grid, or could you group by keys and by column values as well? Or does AG-grid set column values as keys already and here we are just defining a key for null or undefined values?

Comment: Please disregard my first comment. This worked brilliantly. I understand what your code (and what AG-Grid ) is doing now. Thank you!